# Why does useEffect Hook gives double count on first click?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to understand useEffect hook. I want to discuss an issue here, firstly, please have a look at my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const ObjectDependencyExample = () => {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState({ name: "John", age: 25 });
  const [effectRunCount, setEffectRunCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    document.getElementById(
      "alert"
    ).innerHTML = `Effect ran ${effectRunCount} times`;
    console.log("Effect ran due to object dependency change");
    setEffectRunCount((prevCount) => prevCount + 1);
  }, [userData]);

  const handleUpdateAge = () => {
    setUserData((prevData) => ({ ...prevData, age: prevData.age + 1 }));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>User Data</h2>
      <p>Name: {userData.name}</p>
      <p>Age: {userData.age}</p>
      <button onClick={handleUpdateAge}>Update Age</button>

      <div>
        <p id="alert"></p>
        <p>Effect Run Count: {effectRunCount}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ObjectDependencyExample;
```

Why does last two lines of code show different numbers although having the same variable? And why does the innerHtml of `#alert` change from `0 to 2` on clicking the button for the first time?

Here is the link of codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/useeffect2-ldcf4v?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A17%2C5

Comment: Your sandbox link is not working. Either the link is wrong or it is not public

Comment: I ran the code from your question locally and I am not seeing what you're describing. The first element is incrementing from 0 to 1 and up as expected. The second element begins at 1 and increments also as expected (just one step ahead of the first element).

Comment: All of the observed behavior is expected based on the code: the `useEffect` increments the counter when the component first mounts (even effects with dependencies still run on component mount in addition to when their dependencies change)

Comment: code sandbox link does not work, please share it again.

Comment: Nope. I'm signed in and still cannot view.

Comment: Apologies, I've made it public now.

Comment: [a complete guide to useEffect](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/) - by Dan Abramov

Answer (score 0):

> Why does last two lines of code show different numbers although having the same variable?

That's a bit of an over-simplification.  Technically they're *not* the same variable.  They're each a different `const` declared during different executions of the component function.  More specifically, look closely at the order in which you do things:

```
// first...
document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML = `Effect ran ${effectRunCount} times`;
// then...
setEffectRunCount((prevCount) => prevCount + 1);
```

So the first thing you do is update the DOM with the value of `effectRunCount`.  (e.g. `0` on the initial load).  *Then* you queue a state update to increment `effectRunCount`.  That state update will trigger a re-render.  React is pretty smart about only re-rendering the parts that it needs to, and in this case it looks like your manual DOM update survived the re-render.

Aside from the fact that you generally shouldn't be manually manipulating the DOM in React anyway (there are use cases which call for it, but they're fairly rare and you kind of need to know more about how React works to do it)... The result here is not surprising.

`effectRunCount` had a value of `0` when you manually wrote to the DOM.  Then, after updating that state value, the component re-rendered and updated the output of that state value.  What React *didn't* do was update your manual writing to the DOM.  Because why would it?  As a result, these two outputs are always off by (at least) 1.

I suppose the lesson here is to not manually update the DOM like that in React.  You're already outputting the current state of `effectRunCount`, there's no need to try to manually output it as well.

---

> And why does the innerHtml of #alert change from 0 to 2 on clicking the button for the first time?

This one is a bit more subtle, and I may be making some logical leaps in my understanding of it.  But start with the fact that components render twice for development purposes in strict mode.  (Why that happens is outside the scope here.)

You can observe this on the console by seeing this output twice:

> Effect ran due to object dependency change

You can get a little more information by adding that state value to the console:

```
console.log("Effect ran due to object dependency change", effectRunCount);
```

And you'd see this twice:

> Effect ran due to object dependency change 0

Why is it `0` both times?  For lack of a better low-level description of React's order of doing things, these renders happen *quickly*.  The second one isn't a result of a *state change*, but rather the result of *strict mode*.  So both renders occur before any state has changed.  Both of them trigger the effect, so both of them do this:

```
setEffectRunCount((prevCount) => prevCount + 1);
```

This state update is *cumulative* (it depends on the changing value of state throughout a batch of queued state updates), so after both of the renders that state value will be incremented twice.  Which is why it "immediately" (visually anyway) results in a value of `2`.

If the state update were not cumulative (if it depended on the value of the state at the time of the render):

```
setEffectRunCount(effectRunCount + 1);
```

Then both instances of the effect running would be using the same initial value of `effectRunCount` and would both increment that same initial value, so the resulting state value after the strict mode re-render would be `1`.

Comment: I found the answer to part two from the React 18 changes to Strict Mode: *To help surface these issues, React 18 introduces a new development-only check to Strict Mode. This new check will automatically unmount and remount every component, whenever a component mounts for the first time, restoring the previous state on the second mount.*